# How can I pass VSTS URL to Build pipeline hosted on private agent?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have created a build definition with private agent.

For each testcase, I get an option of "Run with options", where I can select by build pipeline.

Can I send PlanId,SuiteId & TestcaseId from "Run with Options" whenever selected by user?
[image]
And want to consume the parameters i.e. PlanId,SuiteId, TestCaseId in python script.

I don't want to use arguments for Python script, as there are multiple testplans and suites.
 Whenever I will select a test case and click on run with  options, is there any way i can send those 3 parameters to my private agent application?

How can I pass the URL from build pipeline to my application ?

Also how to access/read a dynamic http URL in python script?

Thank you